# Character issue with special character in class attribute of tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Characters like `+` (as in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) and `#` (as in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)) are not shown correctly in the `class` attribute.

The tag `c++` is shown as `t-cçç`. Pay attention to the line `<div class="tags t-cçç t-homework">` in the source below:

```
<div class="question-summary narrow" id="question-summary-5237452">
    <div onclick="window.location.href='/questions/5237452/reading-from-file-while-ignoring-parentheses'" class="cp">
        <div class="votes">
            <div class="mini-counts">-1</div>
            <div>votes</div>
        </div>

        <div class="status answered">
            <div class="mini-counts">1</div>
            <div>answer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="views">
            <div class="mini-counts">35</div>
            <div>views</div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="summary">
        <h3><a href="/questions/5237452/reading-from-file-while-ignoring-parentheses" class="question-hyperlink" title="Hello, I have seen similar question, but not the same situation. I am trying to read input from a file which looks like this:

8
0 (2) 2 3
1 (2) 3 4
2 (0)
...


The 8 is the number of items. The 0,1,2  &hellip; ">Reading from file while ignoring parentheses</a></h3>
        <div class="tags t-cçç t-homework">
            <a href="/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'c++'" rel="tag">c++</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/homework" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'homework'" rel="tag">homework</a> 
        </div>

        <div class="started">
            <a href="/questions/5237452/reading-from-file-while-ignoring-parentheses/?lastactivity" class="started-link"><span title="2011-03-08 20:01:51Z" class="relativetime">48s ago</span></a>
            <a href="/users/469935/armen-tsirunyan" >Armen Tsirunyan</a> <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score 11527">11.5k</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I first noticed it at the [front page](https://stackoverflow.com/), but it applies to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%2B%2B) pages as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's intended.

Comment: Could you explain why it's intended? Dots (as in `.htaccess`) are displayed as HTML entities.